# How does messaging queue work in service broker architecture?

Tags: asynchronous, message-queue, microservices, service-broker, asynchronous-method-call

With vague knowledge of service broker I cannot find out where to look understand how messaging queue works in coordinating and setting order that too asynchronously ?

The question may be having a wide scope if I am not wrong but a general explanation for understanding when messaging queue comes into play in service broker would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Will this help? https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture

This is  NServisBus specific, but it can give you some direction